# Python function which writes an output txt file with specific information about original text

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a function that uses a filename as a parameter and creates a new file out_file.txt which contains the original text, line numbers and total no of words up to and including the current line.

so the text in the original txt file is:

> hello hello
> sup sup hey hey
> bye bye bye bye bye

and out_file.txt should be:

> hello hello 1 2
> sup sup hey hey 2 6
> bye bye bye bye bye 3 11

where the first number is the line number and the second number is the adding of the words up to that point.

my attempts haven't gotten far as I'm not sure how to reference to a specific line in the txt file or how to get the word count added.
So here is all I have so far:

```
    def changefile(filename):
    with open('in_file.txt', 'r') as in_h, open('out_file.txt', 'w') as out_h:
        for lines in in_h
```

and here my mind kind of breaks down, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Please show us how your function looks like so far.

Comment: Please do not spam your posts! Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Questions & answers are meant to remain for future reference as well. I've rolled back the question to its last non-spam version.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    words_count = 0
    for line_no, line in enumerate(in_file.readlines(), 1):
        line = line.rstrip()
        words_count += len(line.split())
        out_file.write(line + ' ' + str(line_no) + ' ' + str(words_count) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me understand the process I was having difficulties with.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer answers your question please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You only have code to read the file and iterate over the lines of the file.

The code should further include splitting the line to count the number of words in a line and adding the line number which can be done as:

```
count = 0
idx = 1
with open('Odata.txt', 'r') as inp, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in inp:
        count += len(line.split())
        out.write(f"{line.strip()} {idx} {count}\n")
        idx += 1
```